# Show that $B \cong \mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z$ for a Boolean field B

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The title says it already. For a Boolean ring B which is also a field, I have to prove that the relation $B \cong \mathbb Z /2\mathbb Z$ holds. Any help? I have to prove this as a part of an exercise and in the previous part of the exercise, I have already shown that $x+x=0$ for any $x\in B$ and that $B$ is commutative, so my guess would be that I somehow have to use these facts in my proof.

Comment: Most Boolean rings have zero divisors.  But fields do not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition in a Boolean ring $B$ we have that $x^2=x$ for all $x\in B$. If $x\neq 0$, then $x^2=x$ implies $x=1$ since $B$ is a field (indeed, every non-zero element has an inverse, so multiplying by this inverse we get the result). Hence there are only two elements.

Answer (score 4):

If $x \in B$, then $x$ is a root of the polynomial $X^2 - X$.  Already $0$ and $1$ are roots of this polynomial.  Over a field, a polynomial cannot have more roots than its degree.  This shows that $B$ has exactly two elements.  The only field with two elements is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Why does the implication $x\in B\Rightarrow x$ is a root of $X^2-X$ hold?

Comment: @Tyron What is your definition of Boolean ring, if not $x^2 = x$ for all $x$?

Comment: Oh of course! Thanks for the clarification.